# How to Disable Multitouch in windows phone?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, touch

I had used mouse events, using TouchFrameReported, I wanted it to be single touch, but it is supporting multitouch, how to disable multitouch, in touch frame reported, or is there any idea to implement so that multitouch is not supported..

```
void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (TouchPoint touchPoint in e.GetTouchPoints(this.mainGrid))
            {
                if (touchPoint.Action == TouchAction.Down)
                {
                    currentPoint.X = touchPoint.Position.X;
                    currentPoint.Y = touchPoint.Position.Y;
                    glowDot();
                }
                else if (touchPoint.Action == TouchAction.Up)
                {
                    circPathGlow.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

                }
                else if (touchPoint.Action == TouchAction.Move)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find more information on:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/123e9381-fc0b-441e-a738-dcd35f526a6e/how-to-disable-multitouch

> I wouldn't try to fiddle with the touch messages here. If the goal is
>   to limit the dragging to one control at a time then limit it to the
>   controls. Once one is moving, don't move the others.
>
> At the pointer message level you can track the PointerId in
>   PointerPressed and ignore other PointerIds until you get a
>   PointerReleased or PointerCaptureLost:

*Question: Do you want to disable certain multi-gestures or all?*

Comment: Is it default to Windows phone to support multitouch, Isn't there any tag of sth, on xaml file so that multitouch can be disabled easily

Comment: The following website offers (even) more information about creating a Touchscreen Interface:

http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jprosise/building-touch-interfaces-for-windows-phones-part-2 

Is this useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

After reading http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jprosise/building-touch-interfaces-for-windows-phones-part-2 
I came to know that I was using e.GetTouchPoints
Instead of e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint,,
Now,  I  use e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint, which capture only the first touch points that is being touched,, 
TouchPoint touchPoint = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(this.mainGrid);
and rest of the code,, this solve my problem.